How to add new controlpoints to a curve at a specific time?
If I have a curve, how could I add a new controlpoint at the location in 3D space at time t on the curve?
I've tried looking at the docs, and they don't seem to provide a way to evaluate a bezier curve for some reason. And if I want to add new controlpoints, I need to specify their location in coordinates.

you can't have it appear at a specific time.

why not? also, do you mean like become visible at a specific time? A curve is f(t) where t is time. I'm trying to get f(t) for a specific t.

Take a look at my code linked in this answer

i would recommend telling us your "end goal" or what you want to do with that additional points. If you just want the coordinates you could e.g. use geometry nodes: the sample curve node gives you the exact position (not of a time, but of a fac value, from 0 to 1, but with an additional map node you can easily map your time to the fac value. Same is true for the free add-on animation nodes, which has a similar node: evaluate curve.
